# A conditional statement during a for loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

This is my attempt of a simple example (it seems pointless) but the idea is bigger than this simple code.

During a for loop, if something happens, I want to skip this step of the for loop and then add an extra step on the end.

1. I am trying to create a list of numbers, that do not include the number 8.
2. If the code creates an 8, this will mean that exitflag is equal to 1.
3. Can I adapt this program so that if the `exitflag=1`, the it will remove that result and add another loop.

The code:

```
for i = 1:1000
    j = 1+round(rand*10)
    if j == 8
        exitflag = 1
    else
        exitflag = 0 
    end
    storeexit(i)=exitflag;
    storej(i)=j;
end
sum(storeexit)
```

I would ideally like a list of numbers, `1000` long which does not contain an `8`.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut its not about the numbers here, I'm giving a simple example....

Comment: I think what you want to do is repeat the same step of the loop until the result is not an 8. Is that right?

Comment: @CrisLuengo absolutely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you want to do is 1000 iterations of the loop, but *repeat* a loop iteration if you don't like its result, instead of tagging the repeat at the end, what you can do is loop inside the `for` loop until you do like the result of that iteration:

```matlab
stores = zeros(1000,1); % Note that it is important to preallocate arrays, even in toy examples :)
for i = 1:1000
    success = false; % MATLAB has no do..while loop, this is slightly more awkward....
    while ~success
       j = 1+round(rand*10);
       success = j ~= 8;
    end
    storej(i) = j; % j guaranteed to not be 8
end
```

Comment: @LiorCohen this is what I meant with the greatest respect

Comment: Thanks, its got me thinking but not exactly what I was looking for, it doesn't solve what I was looking for, as in the actual example something else has to run before I know that j = 8 and I cant just assume that j might be 8.

Comment: @user30609: Could you please elaborate? Maybe edit your question to clarify this point? The initialization here (`j=8`) is just to get the `while` loop to run once. Inside the while loop, you run your code, and the while loop repeats until you are happy with the result of the code. Usually I'd write `do <something> while <condition>`, but MATLAB doesn't know that syntax. So instead I need to initialize `j` to the failure state, so that the while loop runs at least once. I rewrote the code to make this point more obvious.

Comment: Ok, i think I come with a solution, but I need j to equal a number before I can proceed?

Comment: @user30609: Maybe the rewritten code is easier to adapt to your particular situation? It's the same logic in principle.

Answer (score -1):

No.

With for loop, the number of loops is determined on the loop start and it is not dynamic.

For doing what you want, you need to use a while loop.

Comment: Surely this is a poor answer. No with an explanation of no, wouldn't it be helpful for the OP and the rest of the community if you provided an example of your method working.